# Creating a Test Class for a Custom Controller with Standard and Custom Objects

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

I created a Visualforce page + a Customer controller in order for users get more depth in their searches so they can do it by Super Customers.  I have a mixture of Standard and Custom objects and I am unsure how to really begin.  I started off small just trying to get my `getAcct` method to get coverage but I am stuck at even doing that.  I have been reading through the workbooks, but my time constraints isn't allowing me enough time to get through all of the documentation.. Any help would be great

Controller

```
 Public with sharing class SuperSearchController {

        Public List<Opportunity> optyList {get;set;}
        Public List<Lead> leadList{ get;set; }
        Public List<Split__c> splitList{get;set;}
        Public List<Quote> qList{get;set;}
        Public List<Sampling__c> sampList{get;set;}
        public List<Contact> contacts {get;set;}
        public List<Case> cList {get;set;}
        public List<Account>aList{get;set;}
        public List<Quote_Part__c>qPartList{get;set;}
        public List<Part__c> oPartList{get;set;}
        private final Account stdAcctCtrl;
        private ApexPages.StandardController controller;
        public String superCustomer {get;set;}
        private String soql {get;set;}
        String alias;

        public SuperSearchController(){
           superCustomer = '';
      }
        private static Map<Id, Account> getAccountMap(String alias) {
        String aliasLike = '%' + alias + '%';
        Map<Id, Account> m = new Map<Id, Account>([
                SELECT Id, Name, Super_Customer1__r.Name
                FROM Account
                WHERE Super_Customer1__r.Name like :aliasLike
                ]);
        return m;
    }

        public List<Split__c> getSplits(Set<Id> accountIds) {
            return [
                SELECT Name,id,CreatedById,End_Customer_Account__c,Production_Site_Address__c
                FROM Split__c
                WHERE End_Customer_Account__c IN: accountIds or Production_Site_Address__c IN: accountIds 
                ];

        }

        public List<Account> getAcct(Set<Id> accountIds){
            system.debug('Account ids ' + accountIds);
            return[Select name,id,Super_Customer1__r.Name From Account 
                    Where id IN: accountIds];
        }

        public List<Opportunity> getOpps(Set<Id> accountIds){
            return [
            Select Name,StageName,AccountId,Expected_Platform_Freeze_Date__c,Anticipated_Production_Date__c,Market_Sector__c
            From Opportunity 
            WHERE AccountID IN: accountIds   
            ];
        }

        public List<Part__c> getOParts(Set<Id> accountIds){
            return [Select Name,Account__c,Opportunity__c,Product__c 
            FROM Part__c
            WHERE Account__c in:accountIds
            ];

        }

        public List<Quote_Part__c> getQPart(Set<Id>accountIds){
            return[
            SELECT Quote_Customer__c, Quote_Customer_1__c 
            FROM Quote_Part__c 
            WHERE Quote_Customer__c IN: accountIds
            ];

        }
     /* public List<Opportunity> getSamp(Set<Id> accountIds){
            return [
            Select Name,ID 
            From Sampling__c 
            WHERE Account_name__c IN : accountIds      
            ];
            //  
        }*/

        public List<Case> getCase(Set<Id> accountIds){
            return[
            Select CaseNumber,Id,Status,Territory__c,Region__c,contactId,origin,subject
            From Case
            Where AccountID IN: accountIds];
        }


        Public PageReference runSearch() {    

        Map<Id, Account> accountMap = getAccountMap(superCustomer);

        if (!accountMap.isEmpty()){        
                this.optyList = this.getOpps(accountMap.keySet());
                //  this.sampList = this.getSamp(accountMap.keySet());
                this.cList = this.getCase(accountMap.keySet());
                this.alist =this.getAcct(accountMap.keySet());
                this.qPartlist = this.getQPart(accountMap.keySet());
                this.oPartList = this.getOParts(accountMap.keySet());
                this.splitList = this.getSplits(accountMap.keySet());
                // Repeat for other types
        }  
        return null;
        }
    }
```

> Test class + `Error Method does not exist or incorrect signature:
>   [SuperSearchController].getAcct(SOBJECT:Account)`

```
@isTest static void test_method_one() {
         Account a = new Account(Name = 'Test Account');
         insert a;
         system.assertNotEquals(a.id,null);

         Contact c = new Contact(FirstName = 'Joe', LastName = 'Schmoe');
         insert c;
         system.assertNotEquals(c.id,null);

     /*    PageReference pg = Page.SuperCustomerSearch;
         Test.setCurrentPage(pg); 
         string accId = a.Id;     
         System.currentPagereference().getParameters().put('id',a.Id);*/

         SuperSearchController controller = new SuperSearchController();
         Account myAccount = controller.getAcct(a);//error
         system.assertEquals(a.Id, myAccount.Id);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `getAcct` method takes in a set of IDs as parameter:

`public List<Account> getAcct(Set<Id> accountIds){`

When you're calling it from your test method you're passing a String (the account Id):

`Account myAccount = controller.getAcct(a);`

Also the method returns a List of accounts and not just a single account.

Change this line to:

```
Set <Id> accountIds = new Set <Id> ();
accountIds.add(a.Id);
List <Account> myAccounts = controller.getAcct(accountIds);
```